# How to import .txt file in Scala

Tags: scala, import

Hi im new to programming, how do i import a .txt file? My code cant find the file, is there any specific directory it has to be put into?

My code:

```
object Zettel01 extends App {
import scala.io.Source

object Suchtest {
  val gesch = Source.fromFile("DieUnendlicheGeschichte.txt").getLines()
  for (w <- gesch) println(w)
}
}
```

I have tried different code but the problem is always the same, i cant find the .txt file...

Thanks in advance for any help
Flurry1337

Comment: Well... You know... In a global context, if your give your address as - "Flat No - 10" then no-one will be able to find you. You will have to give your complete address. Similarly... you will have to provide full path of your file. Something like - "c:\Users\yourname\documents\YourFileName.txt".

Comment: Tried that, still no luck finding the file...

Comment: Besides every piece of example code i have found to importing .txt files never used any path, they always just gave the file name.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding the downvote. Sure, this is not a rocket science level question, but there is no reason to be arrogant to the author. I consider it a valid question for SO. Therefore, I upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

Every Scala program that you run on your computer is ultimately a `java` process. This process will have a "working directory", just as every process on your computer does. By default, the working directory is the working directory of the process that started it, that is, the current directory of the shell or command-line interpreter at the time when you started your program.

Now, that means it is important to know how exactly you start your program. If you are using a command line and start your program in the fashion of `java MyCoolProgram`, then the current directory of the shell will become the working directory of the program. If you use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, those typically use the project folder of your IDE project as the working directory of the process that they start.

There is a simple way to find it out quickly: You can always print out the result of `new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()`. This will print the full path to the working directory. For example, you can write a little Scala program like this:

```
object PrintWorkingDirectory extends App {
  println(new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath())
}
```

and start it. On the console, you should find the full path of the program's working directory. If you put a file named "DieUnendlicheGeschichte.txt" in this directory, your program will find that file under exactly that file name.

Of course, you don't have to dump all your files into that one directory. You can make subdirectories in order to organize your files better. For example, you might put your file in a path like "resources/text/DieUnendlicheGeschichte.txt".

Finally, I would like to point out that there is also a different way to associate resource files with your program, and to load them. The idea is that you put the code (class files) as well as resources like texts, images, CSV files, XML files and the like into one big file. This would be a JAR file. You can then use `ClassLoader` to access resources inside the JAR file by a URL.

Explaining that process in detail is out of scope for this question; this is just dropping a couple of buzzwords that you (or other readers) can search for in case they want to look up a more elaborated process.

Comment: @flurry1337 Great to know it helped. If you think this qualifies as an answer to the problem, please don't forget to mark my answer as "the" answer (green tick).

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("user.dir") also tells you the working directory.